# How to tell apt-get to switch from Sources.bz2 to Sources.gz

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, kali-linux

I have a clean installation of [kali-2.0.1-rpi.img](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/) on a Raspberry Pi B+. It's connected to the mac via cable and network is working: I can open web pages and ping ips from the pi.
After booting and logging in as root, when I try to update packages, I only get errors stating that the files could not be found.

```
root@kali: apt-get update
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates InRelease
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://http.kali.org sana InRelease
Ign http://http.kali.org sana Release.gpg
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates Release
Ign http://http.kali.org sana Release
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main armel Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib armel Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free armel Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://http.kali.org sana/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org sana/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org sana/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org sana/main armel Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org sana/non-free armel Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org sana/contrib armel Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org sana/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org sana/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org sana/non-free Translation-en
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates/main armel Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates/contrib armel Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates/non-free armel Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/non-free/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/contrib/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/non-free/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I check which files `apt-get` is looking for

```
root@kali:~# apt-get update --print-uris
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/source/Sources.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/source/Sources.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_contrib_source_Sources 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/non-free/source/Sources.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_non-free_source_Sources 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/binary-armel/Packages.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_main_binary-armel_Packages 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/binary-armel/Packages.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_contrib_binary-armel_Packages 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/non-free/binary-armel/Packages.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_non-free_binary-armel_Packages 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_contrib_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_main_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/non-free/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/InRelease' security.kali.org_kali-security_dists_sana_updates_InRelease 0
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/source/Sources.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/non-free/source/Sources.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_non-free_source_Sources 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/contrib/source/Sources.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_contrib_source_Sources 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/binary-armel/Packages.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_main_binary-armel_Packages 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/non-free/binary-armel/Packages.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_non-free_binary-armel_Packages 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/contrib/binary-armel/Packages.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_contrib_binary-armel_Packages 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/contrib/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_contrib_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_main_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/non-free/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_non-free_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/InRelease' http.kali.org_kali_dists_sana_InRelease 0
```

I can see, that it's trying to load `Sources.bz2`. However, heading to the  [directory of the file](http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/source) in a browser reveals that there's only a `Sources.gz` available.

How can I tell `apt-get` to load the gzipped version instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time the problem was basically in front of the monitor, but nevertheless I found an option to be set:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz update
```

Adding `--print-uris` shows that `apt-get` is now trying to fetch `gz` instead of `bz2`.

However, as initially stated, that was not the main problem, because the command still fails, not being able to retrieve the `gz` file which is definitely available.
Usually `apt-get` searches for several types and should be able to fetch the gzipped version if only that is available.

The problem here was that `pow` was installed on the Mac.
The network connection to the pi made `ping`s to the outside world possible and any `wget` downloaded a page -- but not the real one but the pow page from the Mac. Thus there was no connection to the update servers.